# JS that selects an option from a dropdown on the screen

Tags: javascript, selenium

Given:

```html
<select name="dealer" d-id="select-dealer" placeholder="Please Select">

      <option name="">Please Select</option><option value="123" name="test">123- test</option>
      <option value="321" name="test2">321- test</option>

</select>
```

I am using test shell to do automated selenium tests and the selector option dosen't work but i have the option to replace it with some js code.

What i need is to do an action on the screen that basically selects the value at a given index from the dropdown.

EDIT:

Came up with another aproach :

```js
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@d-id="select-dealer"] 
and text()='123- test']").click()
```

This also returns an error immediately as i run it

```
Message:
   Timed out waiting for script to complete.

Stack Trace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at SeleniumDLL.WebLib.WebTargetAction.RunScript(String script)
   at SeleniumDLL.TestShellWeb.RunScript(String script, String& scriptOutput)
```

Important adding : The js runs as a selenium script on IE!

Comment: This `"//select[@d-id="select-dealer"] and text()='123- test']"` looks like a broken string. You probably need to escape here : `@d-id=\"select-dealer\"` or use ' ' : `@d-id='select-dealer'`

Comment: I did both, same outcome